Why MUI Slider is jumping back in a React application on Safari, on iPhone 13?
Why MUI Slider is jumping back in a React application on Safari, on iPhone 13? how to fix it?
It doesn't happen the same on Chrome on Windows 10.
Is not jumping back (i.e. to the previous position) if I click somewhere in the slider instead of sliding to a particular position.
"react": "^18.2.0"
import { Slider, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Dashboard() {
  const [sliderVolume, setSliderVolume] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6">Dashboard</Typography>
      <Slider
        value={sliderVolume}
        onChange={(_e, newValue) => setSliderVolume(newValue as number)}
      ></Slider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;

